# How to change FragmentBreadCrumbs's divider

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I have to change the UI of Setting.

Now I want to change the horizontal divider in the image below.I know it's part of FragmentBreadCrumbs, but I don't know how to.
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Note that [`FragmentBreadCrumbs` was deprecated in Android 5.0](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs.html).

Comment: Thanks. My target is only Android 4.4.